# Is it possible to grab info about ads shown to user?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-ads-api

Is it possible to grab ads which are shown to user? Not the ones he created. Using Ads API?

For example if I know the Creative ID (e.g. 6003457682739) can I get info about it?

I've tried to use this code:
https://graph.facebook.com/6003457682739?access_token=

From help: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/adcreative/ Part "Retrieving data for specific creatives"

But no luck, I guess because Facebook allows to grab ads managed by you only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*But no luck, I guess because Facebook allows to grab ads managed by you only?*"

This guess is incorrect.  You can get data managed by others. You will need to get the access_token from the manager of the ad to get their data.